# I want to delete the array whose price is 0

Tags: javascript

I have an array[image] I want to delete the price when it is = 0

Why when I want to delete the array whose price is 0 does not delete all array ?

Where is problem ?

```
var products = [{
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linamazon",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/Amazon22.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "Amazon.com",
    storeName: "Amazon"
  },
  {
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linknewegg",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/NewEgg.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "NewEgg.com",
    storeName: "NewEgg"
  },
  {
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linknoon",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/noon-logo2.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "icon Store/Noon.com",
    storeName: "Noon"
  },
  {
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linkebay",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/ebay33.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "Ebay.com",
    storeName: "Ebay"
  },
];


for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  if (products[i].price == 0) {
    products.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

console.log(products)
```

Comment: consider using `filter` instead.

Comment: When you remove an item in the loop, the index shift down to fill in the gap.....

Comment: You are removing items without adjusting your index. Each time you remove an item, the next item never gets checked.

Comment: As @epascarello and @d-m said the problem is that. The best tricky way to handle it, is `reversing the loop`, it means try to count from `end to start`. like: `for (i=products.length-1;i>=0;i--)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the array in the middle of a loop. This causes the array to shrink, and so `i` is now referring to a different element. When `i` increments, you then end up skipping over a value. One possible fix is to change `i` at the same time you modify the array:

```
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  if (products[i].price == 0 ) {
    products.splice(i, 1)
    i -= 1; // <--------------- added
  }
}
```

Or you can consider using another approach, such as the `.filter` method on arrays:

```
products = products.filter(product => product.price !== 0);
```

Comment: Or reverse the loop: `for (i = products.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Try using something like :

```
const arr = products.filter(x => x.price > 0);
```

You can even add casting to Number();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what @epascarello and @d-m said in comments, **removing them will change the index of items in the array**, so your loop will miss a few of them.

And the standard answer is [what @aayoub-el-aboussi said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423734/7514010)

But if you want to keep the `for loop` for `better performance`, you just have to **reverse the loop**, it means try to count from end to start. As the example:

##### How remove some items in array (without missing) using `for loops`

```js
var products = [{
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linamazon",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/Amazon22.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "Amazon.com",
    storeName: "Amazon"
  },
  {
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linknewegg",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/NewEgg.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "NewEgg.com",
    storeName: "NewEgg"
  },
  {
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linknoon",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/noon-logo2.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "icon Store/Noon.com",
    storeName: "Noon"
  },
  {
    specs: "name",
    shopLink: "linkebay",
    shopLogoUrl: "icon Store/ebay33.png",
    price: 0,
    priceUpdate: "Ebay.com",
    storeName: "Ebay"
  },
];


for (i = products.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
  if (products[i].price == 0) {
    products.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

console.log(products)
```